# RDP Copy file from one server to another server fails "Unspecified error"

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, database-administration

I need to move sql database backup files between one server to another server. Both are on different domains and my user permission levels are different in the two servers. I'm able to copy paste the small files between these servers but files more than 1 GB are not copying with the error message: "Unspecified error". The problem is i'm not able to Copy the files using robocopy or xcopy because from the source server it's not able to read the destination directory and vice versa. Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Anything in the event log?